# Google map tile size and number for an area

Tags: google-maps, tiles

Is there any way to estimate the number of tiles in an area for Google Maps for each zoom level? I need something like this app:

http://tools.geofabrik.de/calc/#type=geofabrik_standard&bbox=-14.885271,8.083153,7.614729,27.393223

but for Google Maps. I also think it would be possible to calculate using this equation for whole earth:

sigma(i^4)

which i goes from 1 to 19 (zoom level) but it calculates for the whole world and gives tile numbers, I can later multiply it into average tile size (I have no idea about this value too).

Comment: OSM and Google are using the same tiling schema so you can use the same tile counts. When it comes to tile size, you can download a few Google map tiles and calculate an average.

Comment: Are you sure about that?So I can easily calculate tile numbers.